# Rolling window with conditions using PySpark and how to make it faster on local machine?

Tags: python, pyspark, window-functions

I've got csv file of approxiamately 500 Mb and 1,5 million rows. I've made PySpark dataframe.
Now I need to use window function and count how many times both condition #1 and condition #2 appeared at once in the window of 3600 sec. In the end I need to find maximum number of appearance of these events in 3600 sec gap.
My code is below:

```
df = df.withColumn('result', F.when((F.col("column_1") == 'condition_1') & (F.col('column_2') == 'condition_2'), 1).otherwise(0))

winSpec = Window.partitionBy('result').orderBy('date').rangeBetween(-3600, 0)

df = df.withColumn('rol_func', F.sum(F.col("result")).over(winSpec))

df.agg(F.max("rol_func")).show()
```

It works and gives correct result, but it's so slow compared to Pandas code. I work on local machine. So my question is how can I improve the performance of PySpark on it?

Comment: (Py)Spark is designed for data processing on a cluster of machines, if you're running it on a single machine then I'd stick with Pandas.